# Hhow to filter by date of DataFrame in python function

Tags: python, pandas

I tried the following code.

The result1 is filtered by a given date, but the result2 isn't filtered. 
How can I filter by date in a function?

```
import pandas as pd
over20='https://gist.githubusercontent.com/shinokada/dfcdc538dedf136d4a58b9bcdcfc8f18/raw/d1db4261b76af67dd67c00a400e373c175eab428/LNS14000024.csv'

df_over20 = pd.read_csv(over20)
display(df_over20)

result1=df_over20[df_over20['DATE']>='1972-01-01']
display(result1)


def changedate(item):
    # something more here
    item['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(item['DATE'])
    start=pd.to_datetime('1972-01-01')
    item[item['DATE']>=start]
    return item

result2=changedate(df_over20)
display(result2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I would make the Date column the index by running:

```
df.index = df[“DATE”]
df.drop(“DATE” , inplace = True , axis = 1 )
```

Try to use the index column

```
date = DT.datetime(‘2020-04-01’)
x = df[df.index > date]
```

You can also use the following command to make sure your index is a datetime index

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime( df.index )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not compare datetime by own string. it leads bad result.
please use this.

```
import datetime
 def compare (date1,date2):
   date1 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(date1).timestamp()
   date2 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(date2).timestamp()
   if(date1>date2):
     return 1
   elif(date1 == date2):
     return 0
   else:
     return -1
```